# What is an example of a simple formal language that allows to write a complete proof that a particular Turing machine halts?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, proof-theory, turing-machines, provability

What is the simplest formal language $L$ such that if a particular Turing machine $M_i$ halts, then there exists a finite formula $F$ in $L$ such that $F$ is a **complete proof** that $M_i$ halts (for clarity, we assume that $F$ is required to include the complete description of $M_i$)?

I think that the first part of $F$ is assumed to contain the complete description of $M_i$ and the second part of $F$ is assumed to contain the [computation history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_history) of $M_i$. But what is an example of $L$ that allows to write such formulas (assuming that I want $L$ to be as simple as possible)?

Comment: How do you define "$L_1$ is simpler than $L_2$"?

Comment: I think that informal, intuitive approach works here. Basically, it depends on a person $X$ who answers this question: if $X$ wants to provide a complete description of $L$ for the average reader of Math.SE, then we can assume that $L_1$ is simpler than $L_2$ if the complete description of $L_1$ contains less symbols (where one symbol is encoded by one 32-bit value in Unicode [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)) than the complete description of $L_2$ (assuming that the natural language of the description is English).

Comment: Then try to beat this: "Emulate $M_i$ with production rules (left tape)(old state)(right tape) $\to$ (new left tape)(new state)(new right tape) and $S\to$(empty tape)(initial state). Then the very fact that something with a halting state is in $L$ is proof that $M_i$ halts."